# Button click the parameter does not pass to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I click the Button ,but the parameter does not pass to my view.The Button will working on properly,I have just put it on alert message  The alert message will be shown.
    My view as follws

```
       <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>               
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                   $('#AddToCard').click(function () {
                    var ProductID = $('#txtproductID').val();
                    var Quantity = $('#txtQuantity').val();
                    var NetAmt = $('#txtNetAmt').val();
                    var ProName = $('#txtPN').val();
                    alert("ID="+ProductID+"QTY=" + Quantity+"NETAMT=" + NetAmt+"Name=" + ProName);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '../Home/AddOrderItem',
                       data: { productCode: ProductID, quantity: Quantity, NAMT: NetAmt, PName: ProName },

                        success: function (data) {
                             if (data) {
        //                        alert("Added To your Card");
                            }
                      }
                    });
                });


            });
        </script>
```

**My cotroller is**

```
       public void AddOrderItem(Int64 productCode, int quantity, decimal NAMT, string PName)
            {
                //adds an item to the current order
                OrderDO order = (OrderDO)Session["Order"];
                decimal TotAmt = quantity * NAMT;
                order.Items.Add(new OrderItem(productCode, quantity,NAMT,PName,TotAmt));
                Session["Order"] = order;
              }
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from AddOrderItem, how can success be called ? What is the parameter that you want to pass ?

Comment: I am apply the below code, after the that the ajax function could not be working                                        public ActionResult AddOrderItem(Int64 productCode, int quantity, decimal NAMT, string PName)
{
    //adds an item to the current order
    OrderDO order = (OrderDO)Session["Order"];
    decimal TotAmt = quantity * NAMT;
    order.Items.Add(new OrderItem(productCode, quantity,NAMT,PName,TotAmt));
    Session["Order"] = order;

    return Json(order, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

Answer (score 0):

To get back result from controller to View you should return Json object.

```
public ActionResult AddOrderItem(Int64 productCode, int quantity, decimal NAMT, string PName)
{
    //adds an item to the current order
    OrderDO order = (OrderDO)Session["Order"];
    decimal TotAmt = quantity * NAMT;
    order.Items.Add(new OrderItem(productCode, quantity,NAMT,PName,TotAmt));
    Session["Order"] = order;

    return Json(order, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```